# Rails app shows a wrong root page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

So I have this in my routes:

```
resources :articles
root 'articles#new'
```

but I want my urls look not like **domain/articles/1**, but like **domain/1**.
So i change my routes to:

```
resources :articles, path: ''
root 'articles#new'
```

It changes my root page to 'articles#index', but I still want it to be 'articles#new'.
How do I fix it?

Comment: Both routes point to the same endpoint, the root of your url, and Rails matches with the first one which is `articles#index`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I just changed the code to:

```
root 'articles#new'
resources :articles, path: ''
```

And it worked